# shorter synonym of "underlying set"

Tags: terminology

Given a structure on a set $X$, e.g. a group $G=(X,+,0)$, we usually call $X$ the "underlying set". Is there a shorter word for this?

Comment: [carrier set](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carrier_set) or carrier.

Comment: Dunno if this is what you're looking for, but you could use $U(G)$ if you've established that $U$ refers to the forgetful functor (so this could be useful in a longer text, I suppose).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is "universe" another synonym for "underlying set" or did I dream that?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, yes carrier is what I was looking for!

Comment: While "carrier set" is perfectly cromulent, I don't see anything wrong with "underlying set".  I would also be a little hesitant to use "carrier set", as it has other meanings in other parts of mathematics (e.g. in the study of [hyperfunctions](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Hyperfunction)).  @MauroALLEGRANZA:  in the interest of providing an answer to the question, may I suggest that you convert your comment to an answer?